# how to get clicked Button attribute Id and value in jquery

Tags: html, jquery

i wanna get button id and value when clicked by this situation

this is my html i write this html tags

```
<div class="row ">
    <div class="col-lg-8 m-auto border">
        <button id="btnadd" class="btn btn-info">add attribute</button>
        <br>
        <div class="row border" id="holder">
            <div id="mainholder1" class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-5">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control form-text" name="title" placeholder="enter title">
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-5">
                    <textarea name="desc" id="desc" class="form-text form-control"></textarea>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-2">
                    <button class="btn btn-danger mybtn">remove</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and in my script file i added this
and i just want access to the clicked button by calling function

```
 $(function () {
        var i = 1;
        $("#btnadd").click(function () {

            var elemnts =
                '<div class="row" id="holder' + i++ + '">' +
                '<div class="col-lg-5">' +
                '<input type="text" class="form-control form-text" name="title" placeholder="enter title">' +
                '</div>' +
                '<div class="col-lg-5">' +
                '<textarea name="desc" id="desc" class="form-text form-control"></textarea>' +
                '</div>' +
                '<div class="col-lg-2">' +
                '<button id="hhs" onclick="hii()" class="btn btn-danger mybtn" value="' + i + '">remove</button>' +
                '</div>' +
                '</div>';

            $("#holder").append(elemnts)
        })

    })

    function hii(){
        // i wanna get access to the clicked button
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Abbas. Please try below.

```
$(function () {
    var i = 1;
    $("#btnadd").click(function () {

        var elemnts =
            '<div class="row" id="holder' + i++ + '">' +
            '<div class="col-lg-5">' +
            '<input type="text" class="form-control form-text" name="title" placeholder="enter title">' +
            '</div>' +
            '<div class="col-lg-5">' +
            '<textarea name="desc" id="desc" class="form-text form-control"></textarea>' +
            '</div>' +
            '<div class="col-lg-2">' +
            '<button id="hhs" class="btn btn-danger mybtn" value="' + i + '">remove</button>' +
            '</div>' +
            '</div>';

        $("#holder").append(elemnts)
    })
    $(document).on('click', '#hhs', function() {
        // hii function code should be here.
    });
});
```

Hope this helps. Happy coding~ :)

Comment: tnk u very much its solved , in ur code i added  alert($(this).attr('value')) and its solved , but why its not worked in my function ?

Comment: The click() binding you're using is called a "direct" binding which will only attach the handler to elements that already exist. It won't get bound to elements created in the future. To do that, you'll have to create a "delegated" binding by using on()

Comment: tnk u so much , it was so helpfull for me